# Отличие EJB1.1 от EJB3

Tags: java-ee

Добрый день!
Я разбираюсь в EJB3, но не знаю EJB1.1.
Мне лень разбираться в устаревшей версии, расскажите, в чем их отличие и получите плюс к карме и рейтингу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А с google.com не получилось разобраться?

Первое, что нашлось:

- https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/08/18/ejb3.html
- http://www.javatutoronline.com/ejb1-vs-ejb2-vs-ejb3/